# Check if subclass implements an interface in parent class?

Tags: java, interface

I know how to check if an object implements an interface. But how do I check in the parent class if the subclass implements the interface?

Suppose

```
class A {

   //What can I do to check here?

}
```

and

```
class B extends A implements Listener{


  }
```

and

```
class C extends A {


  }
```

Here `B` implements the interface `Listener` but `C` does not. How do I check it?

Comment: If `A` contains code that needs to know that, you should reconsider your design. At least add some example code why that would be necessary.

Comment: yes, "Why" is a relevant question. Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 4):

`this` or `Object.getClass()` returns the reference respectivly the Class object at runtime.
So you can use them to check whether the object or the class implements a specific interface.

If you manipulate classes :

```
if (Listener.class.isAssignableFrom(C.class)){
   ...
}
```

If you manipulate instances :

```
if (this instanceof Listener){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check in the parent class if the `this` variable implements your `Listener`-interface, because the `this`-variable references to the actual subclass object:

```
public class A{
    public void doSomething(){
         if(this instanceof Listener){
             // do something if it is a listener
         }
    }
}
```

So above code block will be executed for the subclass `B` but not for `C`

Answer (score 1):

You can just have a method like this in `A`:

```
public void maybeAddListener() {
    if (this instanceof Listener) {
        somethingOrAnother.addListener((Listener) this);
    }
}
```

Whether or not that's a good idea depends on what exactly you want to achieve with this. If subclasses of `A` are likely to implement `Listener` then a better idea is to just implement it in `A` with a do-nothing implementation and let subclasses override the appropriate methods.

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of right now is creating an object of that class and checking with

```
    object instanceof interface
```

Or

```
     object.getClass().getInterfaces()
```